# How to correctly end tornado requests?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using Tornado as an API for a basic request to send an email.
Depending on the sending result, I'd like to finish the request accordingly.

This is what I've done:

```
def get_routes(tornado_config):
    return [
        (r"/send", EmailHandler, tornado_config)
    ]
```

This is inside `EmailHandler`, result is the return of sending email:

```
if result:
        self.set_status(200)
        self.finish(json.dumps({"status":"ok", "result":result}))
        return ''
else:

        self.set_status(500)
        self.finish(json.dumps({"status": "error", "result":result }))
        return ''
```

The problem is that `self.set_status (500)` doesn't seem to add the 500 header.

Other solution would be:

```
    if result:
        return "ok"
    else:

        return "Message not sent"
```

But this doesn't respect any standard, as it gets returned at a json `{"status":"success", "data":false}` or something like that, even when the sending of email fails.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `write`:

```
self.write({"status":"ok", "result":result})
```

instead of `self.finish`.